# Cannot use Add-DistributionGroupMember cmdlet inside workflow

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-workflow

I am trying to use `foreach -parallel` construction in my PowerShell script. The script is the following:

```
    Param([string]$MAIL_GROUP,
  [string]$INPUT_GROUP_MEMBERS_STRING)
Try
{
$ExSession = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange –ConnectionUri ‘MyExchange’

Import-PSSession $ExSession

Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $True
    $RealGroupUsers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $MAIL_GROUP | Select -ExpandProperty Primarysmtpaddress
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$InputGroupUsers = New-Object ([System.Collections.ArrayList])
    $INPUT_GROUP_MEMBERS_STRING.Split(';',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | foreach {$InputGroupUsers.Add($_.Trim())} | Out-Null
    $InputGroupUsers = $InputGroupUsers |  ? { $_ } | sort -uniq

    workflow Test-Workflow
    { 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]$RealGroupUsers,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]$InputGroupUsers)
    $emails = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $RealGroupUsers -DifferenceObject $InputGroupUsers
    foreach -Parallel ($email in $emails)
    {
        if($email.SideIndicator -eq "=>")
        { Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $MAIL_GROUP -Member $email.InputObject;}
        elseif($email.SideIndicator -eq "<=")
        { Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $MAIL_GROUP -Member $email.InputObject -Confirm:$false;}
    }
    }
Test-Workflow -RealGroupUsers $RealGroupUsers -InputGroupUsers $InputGroupUsers
Remove-PSSession $ExSession
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    $Error 
}
```

The script execution returns the error:

> The term 'Add-DistributionGroupMember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Could anyone help me with using `Add-DistributionGroupMember` cmdlet *inside* workflow.

Comment: Can you run the command directly on the exchange server, i.e. outside of the powershell session?

Comment: No, I can't the script is called by web service

Comment: Try this after your session has connected `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010`

Comment: After adding 'Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010' powershell crashes immediately.

Comment: Not sure then, just need to find out which snapin the command is part of